# AS3: addChild multiple instances of library mc not displaying

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to create a small proof-of-concept wherein a TextField is attached to a mc stored in the library and instantiated (via addChild). I can get the script to work for one instance, but if I try to make four copies (as below), only the third(?) instance of the TextField is displayed. 
(image of actionscript deleted) Thank you for your time.

Code follows:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
flash.display.Sprite;

var i:uint = 0;
var str:String = ""; // to be used to give the textField some values
var aGroup:Sprite = new Sprite(); //used to be some holder other than stage to get all the addChild (don't know if this is absolutely necessary
var aUFO:Array = new Array(); // these are arrays that will hold the instantiated copies of the same object
var aField:Array = new Array();

//main process for creating instances
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    var mcUFO:Saucer = new Saucer(); //mcUFO resides in the library with a MovieClip "Saucer" linkage
    aGroup.addChild(mcUFO);
    aUFO[i] = mcUFO;

    aUFO[i].addChild(tFormula); //tFormula is a textField defined elsewhere (previous frame)
    aField[i] = tFormula;

    str = "FillText"+String(i); //used just to temporarily load the textField with some values
    aField[i].text = str;

    aField[i].x -= 21.5; //this is just a rough, quick offset of the textfield to a better postion within the mcuFO
    aField[i].y -= 8;

    var mcDome:Sprite = new Dome(); //mcDome exists in the library with a Sprite linkage
    mcUFO.addChild(mcDome);
    mcDome.x -= 54; //this is just a quick way to relatively reposition the dome over the mcUFO
    mcDome.y -= 35;
}
```

I then follow with a small code to reposition the four instances so that they form a 2x2 stack.

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    if ((i == 0) || (i ==1)) {
        aUFO[i].x = 200 + i*200;
        aUFO[i].y = 200;
    }else{
        aUFO[i].x = 200 + (i-2)*200;
        aUFO[i].y = 100;
    }
}

stage.addChild(aGroup);//I don't know if this sprite is necessary, but I read somewhere that we're not supposed to add instances directly onto stage, but rather add to a sprite and then addChild that to the stage

this.stop();
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question because of http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realize that responders might want to copy and paste the code onto their own systems. I've removed the screenshot and copy and pasted the code. I hope this meets the standards of this site. Again, thank you, in advance, for your time.

Comment: It seems like you have only one TextField, whereas you need to have individual TextField for each Saucer. You could maybe create the TextFields in that same loop, or nest TextField inside Saucer Mc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is not understanding how instances work.

Library is not a storage, it's like a collection of blueprints. Every time you use the **new** operator, you create a new instance by the blueprint you have in Library (or the new instance of the class that is not associated with any particular Library object, like an empty **new Sprite** container).

On the other hand, everything you pre-designed on the stage exist as final instances. If you designed one **TextField**, there actually is nothing more than one **TextField**.

Imagine you have one apple (**TextField** instance) and a machine that produces (**new Saucer**) paper bags. You make a paper bag and put your apple in. You make another bag and put your apple into the second bag. Now you get the picture, right? The first bag is empty now, even though you didn't explicitly specify removing the apple from the first bag.

To solve the problem, you need to have a **TextField** already designed inside the **Saucer** thing in the Library. This way when you instantiate a **new Saucer**, you will have that **TextField** also instantiated to the new **Saucer** from the Library blueprint. Give that **TextField** an instance name (e.g. "Formula") and address it by it. Your code will look like that:

```
// Content container.
var aGroup:Sprite = new Sprite;

// The list of Saucers.
var aUFO:Array = new Array;

// The list of Saucer's TextFields.
var aField:Array = new Array;

// Instantiation loop.
for (var i:int = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    // Create a new instance of Saucer object.
    var mcUFO:Saucer = new Saucer; 
    aGroup.addChild(mcUFO);
    aUFO[i] = mcUFO;

    // Obtain the unique TextField reference from the Saucer
    // you are currently working on.
    aField[i] = mcUFO.getChildByName("Formula");

    // Assign text to the TextField.
    aField[i].text = "FillText" + i;

    // No need, TextField is already positioned by design.
    // aField[i].x -= 21.5; // aField[i].y -= 8;

    // Instantiate a Dome from the library
    // (but you can do the same and pre-design Dome into the Saucer).
    var mcDome:Sprite = new Dome;
    mcUFO.addChild(mcDome);

    // Position the Dome.
    mcDome.x -= 54;
    mcDome.y -= 35;
}
```

Alternately, you can go all-scripty and create new **TextField** instances, but keep in mind that you will need to set every single property of that new instance, or you might not see any text or anything at all:

```
var textArea:TextField;

textArea = new TextField;

textArea.x = 10;
textArea.y = 10;

textArea.border = true;
textArea.wordWrap = false;
textArea.multiline = true;
textArea.selectable = true;
textArea.background = true;

var aFormat:TextFormat;

aFormat = textArea.getTextFormat();
aFormat.font = "_typewriter";
aFormat.size = 12;
aFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT;

textArea.setTextFormat(aFormat);
textArea.defaultTextFormat = aFormat;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess I overlooked the possibility of attaching the text field right onto the library objects because I didn't realize that one could address individual fields by using getChildByName. Thank you for the clear explanation.

Comment: @Greg Glad it helped. Please keep in mind that **getChildByName(...)** method returns an abstract **DisplayObject**, which is fine with this code because **Array** elements are untyped. However, if you want to assign it to a typed variable (for the sake of compile-time control), you will need to tell the code the actual class of the returned object. It can be done by typecasting: **var aText:TextField = mcUFO.getChildByName("Formula") as TextField;**

Comment: You just saved me from an hour (possibly hours) of headache (joyful headache, but headache nonetheless). Thank you.